# Calculating the percentage of each candidates votes

Tags: java, percentage

```
double[]percentage=new double[vote.length];

for (int m=0;m<vote.length;m++) {
    percentage[m] = (double)(vote[j] / total_votes)*100;
}
```

I am trying to calculate the percentage for each candidate, although I keep getting an error while I am running the code. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Without the error, it's not easy to work out what the problem is...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If vote[j] and total_votes are integers, (double)(vote[j] / total_votes) means: Do an integer division, throw away the remainder, then cast to double - probably not what you want.

Comment: What is `j`?  Why are you assigning the same value to every entry in `percentage[]`?

Answer (score 4):

If `vote[j]` and `total_votes` are `int`, you will get `0`.

You need to cast one of them to double before the division :

```
percentage[m] = ((double)vote[m] / total_votes)*100;
```